# Google App Engine reset memcache statistics

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

I've flushed memcache using flush_all() and by hitting the Flush Cache button in my deployed app Memcache Viewer, however the statistics are not resetting. Is there anyway to reset the statistics?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than those two options, no. If you believe that this is a bug (or feature request), please file one in the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).